QGIS Map doesn't show all the points imported with a CSV file after dezooming
I’m working on a historical map using QGIS, incorporating city names onto it. I have my OpenStreetMap, the historical map is georeferenced, and I’ve imported all my cities from a CSV file. However, I’m running into an issue: not all the points (representing cities) from the CSV are visible on the map. When I zoom in or out to see the entire map, some city points disappear.


do the points which you can't see have anything in common? can you add a screen shot to give us more to go on

did you cross checked the number of rows in csv file outside of qgis and number of features of the imported csv in qgis from within qgis? if they're not the same then most probably, some of the rows in csv have incorrect coordinates, spaces or typos due to which they're not being imported successfully

Hello. Yes they are all in the same aera at the top of the map or the bottom. And for the second answer : all the points are imported correctly, i've my 60 points, its just that they disseapear when i zoom out. I'm not sure how to put images on stack so there you go : https://imgur.com/a/ZqrDPEO

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Try importing the CSV on a blank project, verify the drawn points are correct with a map base layer, and export the point to GPKG. Then try importing the resulting GPKG to your georeference project. Also I suggest you mention your QGIS version.

Question is resolved. I just put the name of the cities smaller and it does the trick.
